# Efficiently search for NSString in a set

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsstring

Consider a set of thousands of `NSString` objects, in memory.

What is the most efficient way to search for a particular `NSString` in the set? Would using `NSDictionary` suffice? Or is it guaranteed that `NSSet`'s search is O(1) (couldn't find any documentation that says so)?

And would the same strategy apply to `NSData` objects?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? If you just want to determine whether a string (or data) is in the set, that's exactly what `NSSet` is for. If you want to retrieve some other object that's associated with the string (or data), use `NSDictionary`. They are different data structures for different needs.

Comment: Is fast enumeration a nice option?

Comment: @KurtRevis I just want to know if the element belongs to the set. However, I couldn't find any confirmation that NSSet's search order is O(1) in all cases.

Comment: @hpique Take a look at [CFSet.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFSet.c).

Comment: CFSet and CFDictionary share most of their implementation. NSSet and NSDictionary may or may not (depending on OS version, initialization, and other factors) share that implementation, but should generally both be O(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Sets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000136-SW1) shows the following note about sets:

> Note: If the objects in the set have a good hash function, accessing an element, setting an element, and removing an element all take constant time. With a poor hash function (one that causes frequent hash collisions), these operations take up to linear time. Classes such as NSString that are part of Foundation have a good hash function.

So for `NSString` you could expect constant time based on the above.

Answer (score 0):

`NSSet` uses hash table in its implementation and tests for equality between all elements that are in hash collision. So performance is directly tied to the hash efficiency of its elements.